# новый столбец с результатом сравнения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, условия

Столкнулся с проблемой заполнения нового столбца по итогам сравнения 2х столбцов в df:

```
      A      B
0   NaN    1.0
1   1.0    NaN
2  10.0  300.0
3   3.0    3.0
```

Пытался сделать:

```
df['C'] = 'Да' if df['A'] > 5 and df['B'] < 400 else 'Нет'
```

но возникает ошибка:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Желаемый результат:

```
      A      B    С
0   NaN    1.0   NaN
1   1.0    NaN   NaN
2  10.0  300.0   Да
3   3.0    3.0   Нет
```

Направьте пожалуйста в каком направлении копать....
Вот код моего примера:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
                'A':[np.nan, 1, 10, 3], 
                'B':[1, np.nan, 300, 3]
                })

df['C'] = 'Да' if df['A'] > 5 and df['B'] < 400 else 'Нет'

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [14]: df["C"] = (df
                    .dropna(subset=["A", "B"])
                    .eval("A > 5 and B < 400")
                    .replace([True, False], ["Да", "Нет"]))

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
      A      B    C
0   NaN    1.0  NaN
1   1.0    NaN  NaN
2  10.0  300.0   Да
3   3.0    3.0  Нет
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает, но строка 0 и 1 заполняется "Нет", можно все таки добиться заполнением NaN?

Comment: @Владимир, исправил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!